# Use of recursive CTE in UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

Does anybody know how to use recursive cte in UDF . I'm trying to implement my family tree relations with UDF returns BIT.

The code is the following:

```
DECLARE @UserID1 INT,
        @UserID2 INT;

SELECT  @UserID1 = 13,
        @UserID2 = 14;

with famMomRel as (
      select * 
      from dbo.people
      where id = @UserID1 
      union all
      select ft.*
      from dbo.people ft inner join
           famMomRel
           on ft.id = famMomRel.idMother    
     ),
     famDadRel as (
      select *   
      from dbo.people
      where id = @UserID1     
      union all
      select ft.*   
      from dbo.people ft inner join
           famDadRel
           on ft.id = famDadRel.idFather
     ), 
     SpouseRel as (
      select *   
      from dbo.people
      where id = @UserID1 
      union all
      select ft.*   
      from dbo.people ft inner join
           SpouseRel
           on ft.id = SpouseRel.idSpouse
     )
select *
from famMomRel
where  idMother = @UserID2   
union all
select *
from famDadRel
where  idFather = @UserID2
union all
select *
from famDadRel
where idSpouse = @UserID2
```

How to implement it into UDF which returns bit ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the end result that you are trying to acheive here? Why do you need a recursive CTE, surely a person's mom or dad is only 1 level of recursion, do you need grandparents, great-grandparents and so on?

Comment: I also suspect that your spouse CTE may spin out of control - person union with persons spouse union with person spouses spouse (which is person)...do you see where this is going